# React Native - useEffect will render Home twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, render

I want to render my functional component "Home" after i get Data from a function in "useEffect", but when i set my data from the function in my const, my Home component will render again.

If i delete the "set" statement, it will only render once.

When the HomeSrceen render for the second time it will start a Navigation Statement that is in a child component.

Can anyone explain me why this happend and how i solve this problem?

My code:
HomeScreen.js

```
export function HomeScreen( navigation ) {

    const [item, setItem] = React.useState([]);
    console.log('fire home')

    React.useEffect(() => {
        getbannerdata()
        .then(res => setItem(res))
    }, []);


    return (
        <SafeAreaProvider>
            <SafeAreaView style={style.container}>
                <View>
                    <Banner data={item} navigation={navigation}/> 

                    <Text>Home</Text>
                </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
        </SafeAreaProvider>
    );
}
```

banneritem.js (navigation Statement will be triggerd)

```
const BannerItem = ({ item, navigation }) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.cardView} onTouchStart={navigation.navigation.navigate('Setting')}>
            <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri: item.header}} />
            <TouchableOpacity>
            <View style={styles.textView}>
                <Text style={styles.itemTitle}>{item.title}</Text>
                <Text numberOfLines={2} style={styles.itemDescription}>{item.content}</Text>
            </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}
```

bannerdata.js

```
function getbannerdata(){
    console.log('fire bannerdata')
    return fetch ('http://192.168.178.46:8000/intranet/messages/', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },

    })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((resData) => {
            return resData;
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))

};

export { getbannerdata }
```

output Terminal

```
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 634ms.
Running application on Léons iPhone.
fire home
fire bannerdata
fire home
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to render my functional component "Home" after i get Data from a function...

Then you must get the data from `getbannerdata` in the parent component, and pass it to `HomeScreen` as a prop. There's nothing you can do in `HomeScreen` to prevent the component being rendered before the data from `getbannerdata` arrives.

In general, with components, you have two choices when there's an async process to get their content:

1. Do it in the component, and handle rendering the case where the component doesn't have the data yet (perhaps with a "loading" message or similar).
2. Don't create the component until you have the data, which means doing it in the parent.

Example of #1:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function getbannerdata() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, 800, "This is the banner");
    });
}

const HomeScreen = () => {
    const [banner, setBanner] = useState(null);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        getbannerdata().then(banner => setBanner(banner));
    }, [banner]);
    
    return (
        <div className="boxed">
            This is <code>HomeScreen</code>
            {banner && <div className="boxed">{banner}</div>}
        </div>
    );
};

const App = () => {
    
    return (
        <div className="boxed">
            This is <code>App</code>
            <HomeScreen />
        </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.boxed {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

or with a "loading" indicator:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function getbannerdata() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, 800, "This is the banner");
    });
}

const HomeScreen = () => {
    const [banner, setBanner] = useState(null);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        getbannerdata().then(banner => setBanner(banner));
    }, [banner]);
    
    return (
        <div className="boxed">
            This is <code>HomeScreen</code>
            <div className="boxed">{banner ? banner : <em>Loading...</em>}</div>
        </div>
    );
};

const App = () => {
    
    return (
        <div className="boxed">
            This is <code>App</code>
            <HomeScreen />
        </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.boxed {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Example of #2:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function getbannerdata() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, 800, "This is the banner");
    });
}

const HomeScreen = ({banner}) => {
    return (
        <div className="boxed">
            This is <code>HomeScreen</code>
            <div className="boxed">{banner}</div>
        </div>
    );
};

const App = () => {
    const [banner, setBanner] = useState(null);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        getbannerdata().then(banner => setBanner(banner));
    }, [banner]);
    
    return (
        <div className="boxed">
            This is <code>App</code>
            {banner && <HomeScreen banner={banner} />}
        </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.boxed {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I found [this article](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) by Dan Abramov very useful. Ostensibly it's about `useEffect`, but really it's about the functional component lifecycle and hooks in general.

Answer (score 0):

T.J Crowder is right,
also because what is happening is perfectly normal.

The flow of what you're doing is :
- home before useEffect is actually fired
- firing of the useEffect
- home rendering again because setItem was called